# Hidden textarea validation

Tags: javascript, textarea

How can I check if textarea is hidden using javascript?

Comment: Hidden as in, not visible? Or not currently on the page? Or rendered as a `<input type='hidden'>` control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet explorer somehow gets confused if you have two elements with same id. Though the things work fine in firefox, they don't in Internet explorer. I changed the id of textarea and it is working now.

Thank You guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('textAreaId');

if (textArea.currentStyle.visibility === 'hidden' || textArea.currentStyle.display === 'none')
{
   /* code */
}
```

Comment: That will only work if the visibility has been explicitly set on the textarea's `style` property (and not, for example, if set by a CSS rule using a class selector)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBox = document.getElementById("myBox");
if (myBox.currentStyle.display === "none" || myBox.currentStyle.visibility === "hidden") {
  alert("Box is invisible");
}
```

-- Works with

```
<textarea id="myBox">Lorem ipsum doloet set amit</textarea>
```

Comment: That will only work if the visibility/display has been explicitly set on the textarea's style property (and not, for example, if set by a CSS rule using a class selector)

Comment: thanks, what does document.getElementById("id") returns if the id doesn't exist in case of Internet Explorer. It is returning NULL in firefox.

Comment: Yogsma, make sure you have the ID attribute set on your textarea. I've updated my answer to reflect this. `getElementById("id")` is also case-sensitive, make sure you write is exactly as I have it. If the element is not found, it will return `undefined` or `null` I think.

Comment: In internet explorer somehow it returns ''.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try elm.getBoundingClientRect() ?

It will give all zero values if the element or a parent has display:none.
With visibility:hidden the element is there and then has a boudning rectangle.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hidden</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:none">
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
  var rect = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  alert(rect.right === 0 ? 'hidden':'visible');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be unhidden in the first place if your css isn't setting it to display: none; ?

If you want to hide it or show it you should just be able to use some JQuery:

```
$(document.body).css( "display", "none" );
```

or

```
$(myForm.elements).hide()
```

And so on.